# Creating virtual raster produces gaps along edges in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, windows-7

I've got almost 1500 .adf raster files of LiDAR data that I need to merge/mosaic into one raster. The most efficient way that I found was to create a virtual raster of all of the files:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list out.txt LiDAR_virtual.vrt
```

and then convert the virtual raster into a GeoTiff:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" LiDAR_virtual.vrt LiDAR_mosaic.tif
```

However, after the first command, the virtual raster that is created has some gap-lines that become more apparent at finer scales and also get translated to the .tif image.

[image: Arrows indicating gaps in virtual raster]

Comment: Are these gap lines at the borders of the original files?

Comment: @AndreJ Yes, they are, but they don't appear when the files are added to the project individually and they are only along this one edge of the field.

Comment: Does the gap apparear when you add the vrt file ? Please post an extract of your vrt

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check on the vrt. If necessary add the nodata tag to inform gdal that the white strips in the border is a Nodata Value - you need to check the value of this data to know.

If you need to set nodata, add -srcnodata to your **gdalbuildvrt** formula :

> -srcnodata value [value...]: (starting with GDAL 1.7.0) Set nodata values for input bands (different values can be supplied for each
>   band). If more than one value is supplied all values should be quoted
>   to keep them together as a single operating system argument. If the
>   option is not specified, the intrinsic nodata settings on the source
>   datasets will be used (if they exist). The value set by this option is
>   written in the NODATA element of each ComplexSource element. Use a
>   value of None to ignore intrinsic nodata settings on the source
>   datasets.

And/or

> -vrtnodata value [value...]: (starting with GDAL 1.7.0) Set nodata values at the VRT band level (different values can be supplied for
>   each band). If more than one value is supplied all values should be
>   quoted to keep them together as a single operating system argument. If
>   the option is not specified, intrinsic nodata settings on the first
>   dataset will be used (if they exist). The value set by this option is
>   written in the NoDataValue element of each VRTRasterBand element. Use
>   a value of None to ignore intrinsic nodata settings on the source
>   datasets.

Check the vrt produced, you're looking for something like :

```
<NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
```

Example

```
<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <NoDataValue>0</NoDataValue>
    <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">input.jp2</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="12000" RasterYSize="12000" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="1024" BlockYSize="1024" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="12000" ySize="12000" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="12000" ySize="12000" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
```

You can have a try at this kind of formula in the **gdal_translate** step if your nodata is 0 :

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" LiDAR_virtual.vrt LiDAR_mosaic.tif -a_nodata 0
```

> -a_nodata value: Assign a specified nodata value to output bands. Starting with GDAL 1.8.0, can be set to none to avoid setting a nodata
>   value to the output file if one exists for the source file. Note that,
>   if the input dataset has a nodata value, this does not cause pixel
>   values that are equal to that nodata value to be changed to the value
>   specified with this option.